# Adding a navigation link to single page bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used a free template to create a small single paged bootstrap website now i need to add an addition navigation link(called events) to that website, but i cannot do it since the editing the html is not enough for complete change.

Therefore can you guys help me on how to add this extra navigational link.

The place I want to add the navigational link

[image]

the only place i could find related to these links index.html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">                          
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="menu active" href="#home" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#about">about us</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#service">our services </a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#team">our team</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#contact"> contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

apart from index.html files theres style.cs, smoothscrol.js, bootsrap.js,custom.js, mordernizer.js etc etc..

please help me to a dd a new link....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy to add a new link that scrolls to a section on the page, I would consider doing a html course because this is very basic stuff add this to your code

```
 <li><a class="menu" href=" #YOURNEWID "> YOUR NEW LINK NAME </a></li>
```

So change were I've put "#YOURNEWID" to ID of the section of the page you want to scroll to for example

```
 <div id="NEWSECTION">
     <h1>This is the section I want to scroll to!</h1>
 </div>
```

so the ID in this new section is `NEWSECTION` so now add `NEWSECTION` to where ive put `#YOURNEWID`

Comment: thanks for answer but it desnt happen like that, when you click any of the existing links the page automatically scrolls down the section it belongs.. but when u add like what you have said it does not happen anything... just have an idea through the below link

https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/doctor-singlepage-medical-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

Comment: Oh you need to set the href to the ID of the element you want to scroll to, so for example `href="#MYELEMENTID"` and then on the element you want to scroll to add `id="MYELEMENTID"`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it scrolls below is that you have an id below say "#about". If you wish to give an external link to about you can give like

```
<li><a class="menu" href="https://www.google.co.in/">about us</a></li>
```

If you wish to give an internal link, Say for example to a page test.html.Create the page test.html and then do this

```
<li><a class="menu" href="test.html">about us</a></li>
```